# Python Xlsxwriter: How can I reset the row number when switching from one sheet to another?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to create a program that can read a .csv file of my exported bank transactions (data (5).csv), assign a category type of that transaction (which are stored in categories.txt as a dictionary) and then, using xlsxwriter module, create a excel spreadsheet with 12 sheets (one for each month) and write to the sheet the Date, Company, Amount and Category of that transaction. Below is the code so far, everything works good except I'm struggling with the spreadsheet writing at the bottom.

```
import csv
import ast
import os
import datetime
import calendar
import xlsxwriter

if not os.path.isfile("./categories.txt"):
    with open("categories.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("{}")
        f.close()

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('MyFinances.xlsx')
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
for i in range(1, 13):
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(str(calendar.month_name[i]))
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Date', bold)
    worksheet.write('B1', 'Company', bold)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'Amount', bold)
    worksheet.write('D1', 'Category', bold)
sheetRow = 1

with open("categories.txt", "r+") as category_contents:
    categories = ast.literal_eval(category_contents.read())
    with open("data (5).csv", "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline="") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = iter(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','))
        next(csv_reader)
        for row in csv_reader:
            date = row[1]
            month = calendar.month_name[datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y").month]
            company = row[5].split("\t")[0].rstrip()
            amount = row[3]
            if company in categories:
                category = categories[company].upper()
            else:
                print(
                    "The category of the transaction of company " + company + " that occurred on the date " + date + " for an amount of " + amount + " does not exist on the system.")
                print("The current categories on the system are the following: ")
                for cat in set(categories.values()):
                    print(cat)
                enterCat = input("From the above list, enter the category of the transaction. If its not listed, enter the category it should be: ")
                categories[company] = enterCat.upper()
                category = categories[company].upper()
            transaction = ((date, month, company, amount, category))
            print(transaction)
            worksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name(str(month))
            worksheet.write(sheetRow, 0, date)
            worksheet.write(sheetRow, 1, company)
            worksheet.write(sheetRow, 2, amount)
            worksheet.write(sheetRow, 3, category)
            sheetRow += 1
    category_contents.seek(0)
    category_contents.write(str(categories))
    category_contents.truncate()
    category_contents.close()
workbook.close()
```

I need 'sheetRow' to reset back to 1 whenever I encounter a transaction in the .csv that didn't take place in the month of the current worksheet. The line that dictates the current worksheet is:

`worksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name(str(month))`

When this line switches to a different worksheet for a different month, the worksheet.write lines below it just resumes of the sheetRow value from before. For example, if there were 50 transactions in January (and sheetRow = 51), that means when the worksheet switches to February it starts populating data from the 51st row instead of the 1st. How can I configure the code so that it starts writing from the first row in the sheet rather than the row from where the previous sheet left off at?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the worksheet

```
worksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name(str(month))
```

you can get the row of the last entry for that sheet from

```
worksheet.dim_rowmax
```

Therefore the next empty row will be

```
sheetRow = worksheet.dim_rowmax + 1
```

Use that rather than incrementing using `sheetRow += 1`

**Note** On a new created sheet `worksheet.dim_rowmax` is `None` so you will need to check for that state before attempting to increment.
i.e. if it's `None` then set it to the first row you want to write to, otherwise increment.